# How do I repeat "Drug Shootout" at Braddock Farm or Weed Farm?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v

I've done it the first time but I can't trigger the event 2-3 weeks later. Several times I tried raiding it again but the farmers don't come back.

- Wikia says it's probably a unique event: http://gta.wikia.com/Braddock_Farm
- IGN says it's available every tuesday with any character from the 2nd time onwards: http://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Raiding_The_Weed_Farm!
- Someone claims it used to work before a patch fix: http://gtaforums.com/topic/605948-weed-farm-not-respawning/#entry1064050226

Answer (score 1):

This encounter was intended to be a recurring event where, while playing as Trevor, you would be able to return to the farm after seven in-game days. It appears one of the Rockstar's updates broke this system, rendering the encounter into a one-time appearance.

According to the [farm's Wikia page](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Braddock_Farm):

> Although the game prompts the player to return in a week or so to steal any future earnings, this Random Event now no longer repeats following a software patch.

It's unclear what patch broke the encounter, but it explains why some forum users were able to repeat the event but are no longer able to do so.